# cant reset input after setting value attribute in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

might seem awkward right, but i simply did equalize the `value` attribute of `input` tag into some random state. but i simply cant even type into the input. the input is supposed to be emptied after click but well, nothing is happening. (sorry if this question is asked before, im really going crazy and couldnt find anything on google which helps me)

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state ={
      address : "",
      name:"",
      main : {

      },
      // city:undefined,
      inputval: "",
    }
  }
  handleName = (event) => {
    this.setState({name: event.target.value})
  }
  handleAdd = (event) => {
    this.setState({address: event.target.value})
  }
  handleClick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.setState({main:{
      address: this.state.address,
      name: this.state.name,
    }})
    this.setState({inputval:""})
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <form>
        <input value={this.state.inputval} type="text" onChange={(e) => {this.handleName(e)}}/>enter full name
        <br/>
        <input value={this.state.inputval} type="text" onChange={(e) => {this.handleAdd(e)}}/> enter adresss
        <br/>
        <button onClick={(e) => {this.handleClick(e)}}>Click me</button> 
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: As I understand, you didn't change the inputval when you are calling the hanleAdd or handleName with onChange inputs event. So all the time, inputval is empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      address: "",
      name: ""
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

handleSubmit(event) {
event.preventDefault();
alert("A name was submitted: " + this.state.name);
this.setState({
  address: "",
  name: ""
});
```

}

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            value={this.state.name}
            name="name"
            type="text"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          enter full name
          <br />
          <input
            value={this.state.address}
            name="address"
            type="text"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />{" "}
          enter adresss
          <br />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Add name attributes to write only one change handler. It makes it so easier. I hope it helps.  Look I wrote again setState to reset after submitting

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing inputval at all. If you want to reset the form after button change. Then below is the solution

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';


class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state ={
      address : "",
      name:"",
      main : {

      },
      // city:undefined,
      inputval: "",
    }

    this.handleName = this.handleName.bind(this)
    this.handleAdd = this.handleAdd.bind(this)
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }
  handleName = (event) => {
    this.setState({name: event.target.value})
  }
  handleAdd = (event) => {
    this.setState({address: event.target.value})
  }
  handleClick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.setState({main:{
      address: this.state.address,
      name: this.state.name,
    }})
    this.setState({
      address: "",
      name: ""
    })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <form>
        <input value={this.state.name} type="text" onChange={(e) => {this.handleName(e)}}/>enter full name
        <br/>
        <input value={this.state.address} type="text" onChange={(e) => {this.handleAdd(e)}}/> enter adresss
        <br/>
        <button onClick={(e) => {this.handleClick(e)}}>Click me</button> 
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```